# Cypress.io: Is it possible to create reports when the tests are executed in graphical mode?

Tags: mocha.js, integration-testing, cypress

Is it possible to create mochaawesome-reports, when the tests are runned in graphical mode?

All tutorials I have found so far, show it only in conjunction with the headless mode.

Comment: you can try another report [Allure](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin) for example

Comment: [liron\_e](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2602426) wrote an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66080107) saying "For mochawesome report try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-mochawesome-reporter"